# How to add a parameter to an existing stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex, stored-procedures, replace, parameter-passing

I want to add a new parameter to an existing stored procedure. Body of this procedure may have been already customized by users so I can't drop and recreate it. I don't need to modify the body, just the signature.

So I thought to do a replacement of the last existing parameter by itself + the new parameter.

```
replace(OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(id)),'@last_param varchar(max)=null','@last_param varchar(max)=null, @new_param varchar(max)=null')
```

It works fine if the following string is found

```
@last_param varchar(max)=null
```

but doesn't work if there is spaces in the string.

I would like to use a regex to be sure it works in all cases but I'm not sure it's possible in SQL Server.

Can you help me please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does not natively support regular expressions. You'll have to look at more manual string-analyzing with the available [string functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx). Something like this:

```
set @obDef = OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(id))
set @startLastParam = PATINDEX('%@last_param%varchar%(%max%)%=%null%', @obDef)
if @startLastParam = 0 begin
    -- handle lastParam not found
end else begin
    set @endLastParam = CHARINDEX('null', @obDef, @startLastParam) + 4 -- 4 = len('null')
    set @newDef = STUFF(@obDef, @endLastParam, 0, ', @new_param varchar(max)=null')
end
```

This isn't very fool-proof/safe though. `PATINDEX()` only gives you the same `%` wildcard you know from `LIKE`, it may match no character, it may match half the stored proc to find the word `max` somewhere entirely outside the signature.

So don't just run this in your customers production **;)** but if you are certain about the current stored proc signature, this might just do the trick for you.